# Receiving undefined method error when monkey patching

Tags: ruby

I'm getting the the error

```
`<main>': undefined method `my_uniq' for Array:Class (NoMethodError)
```

when running the following code

```
class Array
  def my_uniq(array)
    new_arr = []

    array.each do |i|
      if !new_arr.include?(i)
        new_arr << i
      end
    end

    return new_arr
  end
end

test = Array.my_uniq([1,2,3])
```

Any help fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: don't define a parameter and use `self` in your method, then you can call `[1,2,3].my_uniq`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a **class method**, you have to define it with `self` i.e.  `def self.my_uniq`:

```
class Array
  def self.my_uniq(array)
    array.each_with_object([]) do |element, new_arr|
      new_arr << element unless new_arr.include?(element)
    end
  end
end
```

For class methods, the class itself is the receiver:

```
Array.my_uniq([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1])
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to write an **instance method**, you omit `self` and the argument:

```
class Array
  def my_uniq
    each_with_object([]) do |element, new_arr|
      new_arr << element unless new_arr.include?(element)
    end
  end
end
```

For instance methods, an instance of that class is the receiver:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1].my_uniq
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll do some more reading about the difference between class methods/instance methods. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. Cheers.